# Prism WPF unable to load modules

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mef

I am building a simple WPF Prism application, and just building out the basic framework and infrastructure, so am trying to get the application to load with a single module.

I have a WPF application for the Prism app running on NET 4.7.2, set to use the latest C# language version, and a class library for the module also on NET 4.7.2, also set to use the latest C# language version. I have a project reference to the class library in my main Prism application, to make sure it is copied to the output folder at runtime.

My app.config

```
<configSections>
    <section name="modules" type="Prism.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, Prism.Wpf" />
</configSections>
  <modules>
    <module assemblyFile="TomSavano.UI.OperationsModule.dll" moduleType="TomSavano.UI.OperationsModule.OpsModule, TomSavano.UI.OperationsModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" moduleName="OpsModule" startupLoaded="True" />
  </modules>
```

And my module class

```
namespace TomSavano.UI.OperationsModule
{
    //[ModuleExport(typeof(OpsModule))] - This was from my previous sample code from many years back, but recent examples use the line below so assume Prism has been updated
    [Module(ModuleName = "OpsModule", OnDemand = false)]
    public class OpsModule : IModule
    {
        [Import]
        public IRegionManager RegionManager;

        public void Initialize()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

For completeness here are the csproj files

Main app

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <StartupObject>TomSavano.UI.App</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Prism.Mef" Version="6.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TomSavano.UI.OperationsModule\TomSavano.UI.OperationsModule.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TomSavano.UI.Shared\TomSavano.UI.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Module class library

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    <BaseOutputPath>..\TomSavano.UI\bin\</BaseOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Prism.Mef" Version="6.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I check the bin/debug/net472 folder of the main application, I can see the application exe, config and the TomSavano.UI.OperationsModule.dll - so the DLL is definitely in the output folder. However at bootstrap, I get the error

> Prism.Modularity.ModuleTypeLoadingException: 'Failed to load type for
> module OpsModule.  Error was: Could not load file or assembly
> 'TomSavano.UI.OperationsModule.dll' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the path specified..'

Even though the DLL is definitely in the output path. I have tried clean, shut down and restart everything, but still no joy. Can anyone suggest either another reason this might be happening, or any further steps I could take to debug and try and isolate the cause? I thought perhaps it might be a project version incompatibility, ie in the csproj above, one has langversion 10, and the other doesn't, but hoping someone can shed some light on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What *are* the dependencies of your module and *are* they present in the output folder?

Comment: Prism.Mef is the only external package, then just System, System.ComponentModel.Composition, System.Core, System.Drawing, System.Data, System.IO.Compression.Filesystem, System.Numerics, System.Runtime.Serialization, System.Xml, System.Xml.Linq. I've checked the dependency chain of Prism.Mef and they are all in the output directory. The other ones I assume are part of .NET framework. I would think as I've project referenced the module, when I compile, it should include any dependent assemblies too?

Comment: One simple test to do is temporarily add a *project reference* from your application to `TomSavano.UI.OperationsModule`.  Make the app use some public type from the module -- It doesn't matter what it is -- in the app constructor, before it does any Prism work of trying to load modules.  Just create a new instance of the type.  Then run the app and see if it even reaches the constructor.  If it does not, then the problem could be that there's something the *module* depends on that's not there.  You'll likely get a message about it -- in the Windows Event log if not in the debugger

Comment: `it should include any dependent assemblies` better be safe than sorry - set the output path of the module to the output path of the app and add a build dependency or manually copy the module output over